# Can't load search result in Google places after Migrating to the New Places SDK Client vesrion 1.1.0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have migrated my Android application to the New Google Places SDK Client. But I am facing the issue for a particular place "Sai Kripa Hospital & ICU" which was perfectly working before migrating to New Places SDK Client.

Logcat is showing below issue,

```
E/Places: Error while autocompleting: INTERNAL_ERROR
```

dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
```

Source Code

```
import com.google.android.libraries.places.compat.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.compat.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;

Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).
setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(18.901625, 72.810470),
new LatLng(19.463793, 72.816068))).build(MainHomeActivity.this);

startActivityForResult(intent, PICKUP_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Above code is working perfectly for other search places. Please guide if I am missing anything.

Comment: Are you using the Maps SDK as well? if yes, are you using the v2 or v3(beta) version?

Comment: Might also wanna check the way of implementation here - https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity

Comment: Now I found that this is working for older dependency version i.e.             
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0' & Not working for latest 1.1.0 version

Comment: could you please remove 'implementation'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0' and keep 'implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'